# How set font and color on nstextfield in cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfont

I want set font on panel and change the selected font. I am using `NSColorWell` to open and select the color. For font, what can I use?  How can I open the font panel and perform action when font panel is closed?

Currently I am using

```
'- (IBAction)Open_Font_Button:(id)sender
{
    NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    [fontManager setDelegate:self];
    [fontManager setTarget:self];
    [fontManager orderFrontFontPanel:self];
}

- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    font = [sender convertFont:font];
    NSLog(@"%@", font);


}
'
```

but on `chnageFont`, when I change any font or its size it crashes.

Comment: What prevents you then from doing this?

Comment: What have you already tried? What are the problems with your sution? What is not working? You cannot just say "I want this. Thanks."

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have outlets to the ColorWell and textField connected:

```
IBOutlet NSColorWell *colorWell;
IBOutlet NSTextField *textfield;
```

You should set some things about the NSColorPanel:

```
[NSColor setIgnoresAlpha:NO];
[[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setShowsAlpha:YES];
```

When you open or close a window that might display a color panel you should be sure you aren't left with a color panel hanging around:

```
if ([NSColorPanel sharedColorPanelExists])
{
    [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] close];
}
```

Then in your IBAction method for the color well you can get the color:

```
NSColor *color;
color = [colorWell color];
```

You can then set the font and color with:

```
[textField setFont:anNSFont *];
[textField setTextColor:color];
```

EDIT:

I just realized you're also asking how to get a new font from the font panel.

To get a new font from the font panel your code should actually work fine unless "font" (the old font) was never initialized. If font is null then [sender convertFont:font] will return null.

This prints null:

```
- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    NSFont *font;

    font = [sender convertFont:font]; // Reset the font

    NSLog(@"%@", font);

}
```

This prints a font:

```
- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]; // Initialize the old font

    font = [sender convertFont:font]; // Reset the font

    NSLog(@"%@", font);

}
```